# How to force Embedded link to Use My CSS Style

Tags: css

I have to use an embedded search engine in my website which it has it's own style.Now i would like to change just the back-color of table which is presenting in my website. Can you please let me know if this is possible or not?
I already tried adding some style to the header of my page but the link still following the style from original stylesheet.

Thanks

Comment: How are you embedding the search engine?

Comment: well, this is what I got from seach engine company:  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="580" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><iframe align="center" border="no" frameborder="no" height="780" scrolling="auto" src="http://mlsr.realtylink.org/mlsr_get/areaselect.cfm?cid=1177159" width="565"></iframe></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table> I just add this to my page and it works perfectly but as i said I would like to change the table background color by forcing my own style

Comment: 11 questions asked. 2 answers accepted. Sigh...

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible if the embedded page isn't served by the same domain (including port).

That's a security restriction.

If you want this kind of interaction, you'll need to have some control of the server of the embedded page in order to set permissions : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Another (rogue) solution is to fetch the page server-side and to embed it directly in your page.